# How to assign one lambda expression object to another?

Tags: scala, lambda

I have this kind of code where I want store one of the lambda expression in some object.

```scala
var opSpecBoolVal = false
val equalCheck = (x: Int, y: Int) => x == y
val greaterthanCheck = (x: Int, y: Int) => x > y
val lessthanCheck = (x: Int, y: Int) => x < y
val notEqualCheck = (x: Int, y: Int) => x != y

operatorType match {
   case "_equal" => opSpecBoolVal = false; exitCheck = equalCheck; 
   case "_greaterthan" => opSpecBoolVal = true; exitCheck = greaterthanCheck; 
   case "_lessthan" => opSpecBoolVal = false; exitCheck = lessthanCheck; 
   case "_notequal" => opSpecBoolVal = true; exitCheck = notEqualCheck;
}
exitCheck(10, 20)
```

code checks `operatorType` string and if it matches any of the pattern then it sets `opSpecBoolVal` to some value true or false, and it assign one lambda expression to another object and this is where I am finding difficulty in assigning lambda object to some other object. The main motto is not let rest of the code know what `operatorType` string contains and directly use `exitCheck` by passing two argument and obtain a boolean result.

I have worked on one solution in which I got only `exitCheck` part working but couldn't set `opSpecBoolVal` to true or false.
Here is the code which partially worked.

```scala
val exitCheck = operatorType match {
   case "_equal" => equalCheck; 
   case "_greaterthan" => greaterthanCheck; 
   case "_lessthan" => lessthanCheck; 
   case "_notequal" => notEqualCheck;
}
```

I want to set `opSpecBoolVal` to true or false at same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
val exitCheck: (Int, Int) => Boolean = operatorType match {
  case "_equal" =>
    opSpecBoolVal = false
    _ == _

  case "_greaterthan" =>
    opSpecBoolVal = true
    _ > _

  case "_lessthan" =>
    opSpecBoolVal = false
    _ < _

  case "_notequal" =>
    opSpecBoolVal = true
    _ != _
}
```

which outputs

```
val operatorType = "_greaterthan"
exitCheck(10, 20) // res0: Boolean = false
```

To avoid setting `var opSpecBoolVal` as a side-effect, try an alternative pure implementation like so

```
type OperatorType = String
type Operator = (Int, Int) => Boolean
type IsSpecialOp = Boolean

val toOp: OperatorType => (Operator, IsSpecialOp) =
{
  case "_equal" => (_ == _, false)
  case "_greaterthan" => (_ > _, true)
  case "_lessthan" => (_ < _, false)
  case "_notequal" => (_ != _, true)
}
```

which outputs

```
val (exitCheck, opSpecBoolVal) = toOp("_greaterthan")
exitCheck(10, 20) // res0: Boolean = false
opSpecBoolVal // res1: IsSpecialOp = true
```

Comment: `Prototype.scala:7: error: ')' expected but ':' found.
    val earlyExitCheck: (x: Int, y: Int) => Boolean = operatorType match {
                          ^
` Any idea on this error ?

Comment: Remove `x` and `y` from the type like so `val earlyExitCheck: (Int, Int) => Boolean = ...`